# Using not the window.fetch in Svelte component

Tags: svelte

I am referring to this doc: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests, in particular the `load` function it mentioned for NOT using `window.fetch`:

```
/** @type {import('./$types').PageLoad} */
export function load({ params }) {
  return {
    post: {
      title: `Title for ${params.slug} goes here`,
      content: `Content for ${params.slug} goes here`
    }
  };
}
```

I have a `/` page, which has a complex layout and imports many other sub-components:

```
<script lang="ts">
import LatestBook from "../widget/LatestBook.svelte";
import RandomBook from "../widget/RandomBook.svelte";

</script>
...
...
<body>
<LatestBook/>
<RandomBook/>
...
...
</body>
```

So the data fetching job is purposely put into each sub-component:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { BookManager } from "../lib/BookManager";
    import type { Book } from "../lib/Book";
    
    async function fetchLatestBook() : Promise<Book>{
        const bm=new BookManager();
        const lbs=await bm.getLatestBook(1);
        const lb=lbs[0];
        console.log(lb);
        return lb;
    }

    
</script>

{#await fetchLatestBook() then lb}
... // Consumes and displays the book data here
{/await}
```

The page displays correctly but there is a prompt in the console:

```
Loading http://xxxxxxxxxx using `window.fetch`. For best results, use the `fetch` that is passed to your `load` function: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#making-fetch-requests client.js:1776:15
```

Is it possible to define a kind of `+page.ts` for my `LatestBook.svelte`, and many other component level `*.svelte` files?

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't, `+page.js` only exists for *routes* not for individual components.

A good answer to this would depend on why you are doing this

> So the data fetching job is purposely put into each sub-component:

While using SvelteKit the usual way is to load all data for a page in that page's `load` function and then pass the data on to the components instead. Fetching inside the components themselves could be done if you only want to this *client side* in which case you can wrap the entire thing with a check for `browser` https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I know that to have a page to load all the data and pass it to sub-components is a way to do. I will close this topic now.

Answer (score -1):

> So is it possible to define a kind of `+page.ts` for my `LatestBook.svelte`, and many other component level `*.svelte` files?

Yes, each `.svelte` component in the `routes` folder (and its sub-folders) can have their own corresponding `+page.ts` file.

To take advantage of SvelteKit's `fetch()` function in `BookManager`, you need to pass `BookManager` SvelteKit's `fetch()` function when you create a new instance of it, and in it load data using that `fetch()` function (I imagine this should work, have never tried it myself).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will try later today. However, my `LatestBook.svelte` does not reside in `routes` folder but in a separate folder since by right, that "component" is not part of a route.

Comment: @TaylorR Ah, sorry, missed that detail. But no, you have to load data through the `load()` function when using SvelteKit. That's how SvelteKit will know when the component has loaded all data it needs, so SvelteKit can use server-side rendering. So you have to adapt your own code to how the framework works. Not using the `load()` function will work as well, but only for client-side rendering, and never for server-side rendering.